# How are circular generator expressions evaluated in CMake?

Tags: cmake

Consider the following example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(test)

add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(foo 
  PRIVATE "FOO$<TARGET_PROPERTY:bar,COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>")

add_executable(bar bar.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(bar 
  PRIVATE "BAR$<TARGET_PROPERTY:foo,COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>")
```

As you can see, the value of `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` for `foo` depends on the value of `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` for `bar` and vice-versa. You would expect the value for `foo` to diverge to an infinite string: `FOOBARFOOBARFOOBAR...`.

Yet, this puts `-DFOOBAR` on `foo.cpp`'s command line and `-DBARFOO` on `bar.cpp`'s.

Why isn't this an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this behavior is not documented (at least at time of writing, when CMake 3.21 is current), the generator expression evaluator tracks whether it has seen a generator expression already and expands circular expressions to the empty string.

This behavior is implemented here: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/688b647238a5345398788ee99e2e7e53e27eaf05/Source/cmGeneratorExpressionNode.cxx#L1495-L1497